# Rename an image before upload in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload, multer

I'm working with `image upload` in angular. The image uploading part works fine but now the problem is I should rename the image before uploading.
I want to know if it will be easier to do so from the `fronend` or from the `backend`.
The framework used for frontend is `angular`and backend is `nodejs`.
Hope someone will help me with this since I dont have much experience with this framework
Thank you.

Comment: it's easier in backend, using [fs.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback) you can save your file with any name you want so you don't have to rename the file before saving it

Answer (score 1):

This is an very opinionated question. On the frontend I imagine your using some sort of form to attach the file. On frontend it could be as easy as this:

```js
formData.append('userpic', myFileInput.files[0], 'chris.jpg');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Answer (score 1):

i can show you an example of code i use to upload a profile image in nodeJS express backend as joosep has given an example for the frontend. my code is as follows:

```
exports.uploadImage = (req, res, next) => {
  const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')
  profileRepository
    .findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
    .then((response) => {
      const fetchedUser = response;
      fetchedUser.imagePath = url + '/images/' + req.file.filename;
      profileRepository
        .updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, fetchedUser)
        .then((response) => {
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'profileimage updated',
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return res.status(500).json({
            message: 'uploading image failed',
          });
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: 'fetching user failed',
      });
    });
};
```

as you can see i set the name for the image when assigining an imagepath for the fetchedUser. in the example i am just using the filename which comes from the frontend request but you can use any name/string you want instead :)

hopefully this can help you choosing the best implementation for your use case